# Increment data load from Azure Synapse to ADLS using delta lake

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

We have some views created in Azure Synapse Db. We need to query this data incrementally based on a water mark column and it has to be loaded into the Azure data lake container into the Raw layer and then to the curated layer. In Raw Layer the file should contain the entire Data(Full Load data).So basically we need to append this data and export as a full load . Should we use Databricks Delta lake tables to handle this requirement. How we can upsert data to the Delta lake table. Also we need to delete the record if it has been deleted from source.What should be partition column to be used for this

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the syntax for delta tables - UPSERT.  Before the delta file format, one would have to read the old file, read the new file and do a set operation on the dataframes to get the results.

The nice thing about delta is the ACID properties.  I like using data frames since the syntax might be smaller.  Here is an article for you to read.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/03/19/efficient-upserts-into-data-lakes-databricks-delta.html

Comment: Thank you  Crafty DBA.we will check to it